# Google Sheet IFS combine with FILTER Function

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, ifs

I have the following Google Seet Table

```
Old New New2
W01
W02 W04
W03 W05 W06
```

I want to create a formular that transforms the table to this one

```
Old  New
W02  W04
W03  W05
W05  W06
```

So any time a switch from Old to New or New to New2 happens should be displayed.

I wrote the following formular but i always get an error:

```
= IFS(B1 = "";""; AND(NOT(B1 = ""); NICHT(C1 = ""));FILTER({A1\ B1}; NICHT(A1=""));NICHT(B1 = "");FILTER({B1\ C1}; NICHT(B1="")))
```

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the results of two Query calls:

```
={
  QUERY(A1:B4,
    "select A,B where B<>''");
  QUERY(B1:C4,
    "select B,C where C<>'' label B '', C ''", 1)
}
```

or in German locale:

```
={
  QUERY(A1:B4;
    "select A,B where B<>''");
  QUERY(B1:C4;
    "select B,C where C<>'' label B '', C ''"; 1)
}
```

The `label` statements in the second query are necessary to suppress the column labels since you want to treat certain columns in `New1` as `Old`.